# How to pass two or multiple parameters using jQuery through a DropdownList?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-5

**HomeController**

```
public JsonResult GetCity(string DistrictID)
{
  db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

cityList = db.Cities.Where(predicate: x => x.DistrictID == DistrictID).OrderBy(x => x.CityName).ToList();       

ViewBag.City = cityList.OrderBy(x => x.CityName);

return Json(ViewBag.City, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CityID, "City", new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityID, new SelectList(" "), "--Select City--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

<script>
                 $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#DistrictID").change(function () {
                            $.get("/Home/GetCity", { DistrictID: $("#DistrictID").val() }, function (data) {
                                $("#CityID").empty();
                                $("#CityID").html('<option value="">--Select City--</option>');
                                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                                    $("#CityID").append("<option value='" + row.CityID + "'>" + row.CityName + "</option>").trigger("chosen:updated")
                                });
                            });
                        })
                    });
                </script>
```

This method returns a City within a particular District (Cascading DropdownList). It is working 100%.
Now I want to return a Suburb based on a District and a City, using similar logic and code. How do I implement this? (Please include all necessary code i.e HomeController and it's View especially the jQuery part)

```
public JsonResult GetSuburb(string DistrictID,int CityID)
{
    ...................
    return Json(ViewBag.Suburb, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) - despite what you may think you code does not _work 100%_. (there are multiple issues with your code - try returning the view for a start). And you should only need `CityID` to get the associated `Suburb` so its unclear why you would want to sent the `DistrictID` as well

Comment: The Problem is my database does not link a Suburb to a City. They are linked through District. A City belongs to a District and so does a Suburb (DistrictID is a foreign key in both tables). A District belongs to a Province/State. Once a gain the City is not linked through a Province. It's how the database is configured, hence I'm having issues with the relationship between City and Suburb.

Comment: Then you should fix you database

Comment: My database has data and relationships already, it's close to impossible making any modifications.

Comment: Then just do `$.get("/Home/GetSuburb", { DistrictID: $("#DistrictID").val() }`

Comment: Yeah I did that already, it's how my code is working at the moment. The problem with this approach is that a District has many Cities/towns. I want a Suburb that is specific to a City. My DropDownList is not neat when a list of Suburbs that don't belong to that City appear. Is there no way to use both the DistrictID and CityID together?

Comment: Yes, You can pass 2 items. `{ DistrictID: $("#DistrictID").val(), CityID: $("#CityID").val()  }`